# How to iterate through security groups in AWS ec2?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to iterate through my ec2 security groups. I have wrote the following code to connect and get all the security groups:

```
security_groups = ec2_conn.get_all_security_groups()
```

Next step I need to use only the group Id from each security group. in my for loop I used this code to print :

```
print(security_groups[group_id])
```

I tried many different attributes instead of [group_id] but I keep getting an error :

"NameError: name 'group_id' is not defined"

What would be the right way to retrieve or print only one attribute from security groups ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of how to iterate over the security groups, and print their group ids

```
import boto
ec2_conn = boto.connect_ec2()
security_groups = ec2_conn.get_all_security_groups()
for group in security_groups:
    print(group.id)
```

Some additional information on manipulating security groups: http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security_groups.html